# Force Push which screws up the Git history

Tags: git

A branch has been accidentally pushed and forced to my project with Git, in a repository.

Now, I am not finding anymore my previous history of projects.

Is there a way to back it up?

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? What is the layout of your git setup? Is the history lost on the remote or your local copy, or both?

Comment: @ravloony Thanks for your concern. The history is lost on the remote and the local copy as well!

Comment: In that case, follow @cforbish's answer, but skip the first step.

Comment: @ravloony
The Git history in both of the remote and the local are the same and the history is gone.

Comment: @MeiMed: My bad, cforbish has it right.

Comment: I did it , nothing has been fixed. It;'s always the same thing

Comment: If your local copy is a clone since the force push (which seems likely given your comment on cforbish's answer, try doing what he suggested, but on the remote, and therefore without the push.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39919/discussion-between-melmed-and-ravloony)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reflog on the remote and the reflog on the local are empty, which seems to have happened here then there is no way of getting the history back, except if there is a backup somewhere, or another coworker still has it.

Answer (score 3):

Git keeps old revision information (even if it seems to no longer exist).  You can find this information with `git reflog`.

If you find the old revision you can:

```
git reset --hard <oldrev>
git push -f
```

Comment: it's not working :( My shortlog only displays the two reps that I have done recently and not the others. It seems that they have been deleted!!!! Any solutions?

Comment: @MelMed, if this did not work, I don't know of any other solutions.